# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following [AWS's Django documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) on EB, but I still get the same error in the logs:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

The documentation is already wrong on where to point your WSGIPath in `.ebextensions/django.config`, but I fixed it to point to my wsgi.py file.

The deploy works, but the site 500s.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Make sure that you are installing packages and running your script on the correct repository.

> site 500s.

There could be several reasons in the 500 status code, check the logs to get more about the error.

```
$ tail -f /var/log/eb-activity.log
$ tail -f /var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
```

Usually, each application or web server stores its logs in its own directory

Comment: `eb deploy` is suppose to handle all of that. In fact, I don't even have a repository. the 500 is a result of django not being installed. The other logs seem fine.

Comment: I see, are you installing Django in whole system or only in the virtual environment.